# Regular expression special

Tags: javascript, regex, vuejs2

I only wanna see few characters in my website in the filed section.
My regex code in the backend is: `[(validator.field) = {regex: "^([0-9][+:\\-\\;]?)+"}];` and it's not working. Any help

So the user should only insert numeric (0-9), ; (semicolon) and : (colon).

Comment: Try this: `^[\d;:]+$`

Comment: Can put (**;** and **:**) in between numbers or just last of that?

Comment: tnx, but not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user can put `(;` and `:)` in between numbers, you can use `[\d;:]+$`.

[See an online demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZJ1klP/1).

However, if you need to match digits first and `:` or `;` *after* them, use `^\d+[;:]+$`.

[See another demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZJ1klP/2).